# Reading Excel file: How to find the start cell in messy spreadsheets?

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to write R code to read data from a mess of old spreadsheets.  The exact location of the data varies from sheet to sheet:  the only constant is that the first column is a date and the second column has "Monthly return" as the header.  In this example, the data starts in cell B5:

[image: sample spreadsheet]

**How do I automate the search of Excel cells for my *"Monthly return"* string using R?**

At the moment, the best idea I can come up with is to upload everything in R starting at cell A1 and sort out the mess in the resulting (huge) matrices.  I'm hoping for a more elegant solution

Comment: what format are the files? `.xlsx` , `.xls`, or `.csv`. Any chance you could upload an example to test solutions on?

Comment: @dww The files are mostly .xls, though I expect .xlsx to become more prevalent.  I couldn't upload real examples without doctoring them beyond recognition, for fear of divulging classified information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this elegantly, but I'm very familiar with this problem (getting data from FactSet PA reports -> Excel -> R, right?).  I understand different reports have different formats, and this can be a pain.

For a slightly different version of annoyingly formatted spreadsheets, I do the following.  It's not the most elegant (it requires two reads of the file) but it works.  I like reading the file twice, to make sure the columns are of the correct type, and with good headers.  It's easy to mess up column imports, so I'd rather have my code read the file twice than go through and clean up columns myself, and the read_excel defaults, if you start at the right row, are pretty good.

Also, it's worth noting that as of today (2017-04-20), [readxl had an update](https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/04/19/readxl-1-0-0/).  I installed the new version to see if that would make this very easy, but I don't believe that's the case, although I could be mistaken.

```
library(readxl)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

f_path <- file.path("whatever.xlsx")

if (!file.exists(f_path)) {
  f_path <- file.choose()
}

# I read this twice, temp_read to figure out where the data actually starts...

# Maybe you need something like this - 
#   excel_sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(f_path)
#   desired_sheet <- which(stringr::str_detect(excel_sheets,"2 Factor Brinson Attribution"))
desired_sheet <- 1
temp_read <- readxl::read_excel(f_path,sheet = desired_sheet)

skip_rows <- NULL
col_skip <- 0
search_string <- "Monthly Returns"
max_cols_to_search <- 10
max_rows_to_search <- 10

# Note, for the - 0, you may need to add/subtract a row if you end up skipping too far later.
while (length(skip_rows) == 0) {
  col_skip <- col_skip + 1
  if (col_skip == max_cols_to_search) break
  skip_rows <- which(stringr::str_detect(temp_read[1:max_rows_to_search,col_skip][[1]],search_string)) - 0

}

# ... now we re-read from the known good starting point.
real_data <- readxl::read_excel(
  f_path,
  sheet = desired_sheet,
  skip = skip_rows
)

# You likely don't need this if you start at the right row
# But given that all weird spreadsheets are weird in their own way
# You may want to operate on the col_skip, maybe like so:
# real_data <- real_data %>%
#   select(-(1:col_skip))
```

Comment: Yes, actually I *am* reading FactSet attribution reports!  I like the idea of reading twice:  once to find out where stuff is, and once again to let readxl do its magic.

Comment: @lebelinoz Hahaha - I felt compelled to answer since I knew the source at a glance, had already written the code (rather, banged my head against the desk a bunch on this problem), and was waiting at work for something to update. It was a good confluence of events.

Comment: I'm voting for this one as the winner because it makes no assumptions about where Monthly Return is.  I ran it over my examples and it worked for a sheet where "Monthly Return" is in cell F3, and one where it's in cell C5.  Bonus points for working in the spreadsheet that actually had the words "Monthly Return" written in a few other cells off to the side (which I hadn't noticed when I originally wrote this question), and for leaving the column sorting/skipping as an after-thought (because, as it turns out, date is not always immediately to the left of Monthly Return).

Comment: @RafaelZayas this is awesome! Is it helpful to add that I'm also beating my head up against the wall around everything done here and then skipping rows between the header column and my actual data. Say there are five,four,or three (depending on the file) more lines between the "Monthly Returns" row and the MARCH-14 and "0.097" row--how!?!?

Comment: @JWalt - If the lines are blankand don't mess up your type parsing, then filtering should work.  If there is random text (say, secondary header rows you'd delete, messing up the type parsing) that's tricker.  I would probably do a third pass of reading of the data - pass 1: to find the first header row.  Pass 2: read the header row (with the `n_max` argument.  Pass 3: read the data (skipping rows from pass 1 & 2 previously), without a header (`col_names=FALSE`), then assigning second pass headers to the column names.  This trades off efficiency/speed for ease & auto-type-parsing though, YMMV.

Comment: I just included [-c(1:5),] after skip_row.

Comment: @RafaelZayas I'm curious how one could rewrite this to read multiple excel files in a folder that are formatted exactly the same in one easy step.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, at the format was specified for xls, update from csv to the correctly suggested xls loading.

```
library(readxl)
data <- readxl::read_excel(".../sampleData.xls", col_types = FALSE)
```

You would get something similar to:

```
data <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(6L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"Apr 14", "GROSS PERFROANCE DETAILS", "Mar-14", "MC Pension Fund", 
"MY COMPANY PTY LTD", "updated by JS on 6/4/2017"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "0.069%", "0.907%", "Monthly return"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

then you can dynamincally filter on the "Monthly return" cell and identify your matrix.

```
targetCell <- which(data == "Monthly return", arr.ind = T)
returns <- data[(targetCell[1] + 1):nrow(data), (targetCell[2] - 1):targetCell[2]]
```

Comment: To expand on this, I would use `data <- readxl::read_excel(".../sampleData.xlsx", col_types = FALSE)` so that you can directly read the excel file without worrying about converting it to a csv. The rest of the code with finding the target cell should work the same.

Comment: @pdil is it actually specified it is a xlsx file? I thought so as well at first, but actually it is not specified or do i miss sthg? However, i will of course add the excel loading if he specifies the question accordingly.

Comment: I assumed that was the case given the formatting of the spreadsheet in the image (font, percents, etc)

Answer (score 4):

With a general purpose package like readxl, you'll have to read twice, if you want to enjoy automatic type conversion. I assume you have some sort of upper bound on the number of junk rows at the front? Here I assumed that was 10. I'm iterating over worksheets in one workbook, but the code would look pretty similar if iterating over workbooks. I'd write one function to handle a single worksheet or workbook then use `lapply()` or `purrr::map()`. This function will encapsulate the skip-learning read and the "real" read.

```r
library(readxl)

two_passes <- function(path, sheet = NULL, n_max = 10) {
  first_pass <- read_excel(path = path, sheet = sheet, n_max = n_max)
  skip <- which(first_pass[[2]] == "Monthly return")
  message("For sheet '", if (is.null(sheet)) 1 else sheet,
          "' we'll skip ", skip, " rows.")  
  read_excel(path, sheet = sheet, skip = skip)
}

(sheets <- excel_sheets("so.xlsx"))
#> [1] "sheet_one" "sheet_two"
sheets <- setNames(sheets, sheets)
lapply(sheets, two_passes, path = "so.xlsx")
#> For sheet 'sheet_one' we'll skip 4 rows.
#> For sheet 'sheet_two' we'll skip 6 rows.
#> $sheet_one
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>         X__1 `Monthly return`
#>       <dttm>            <dbl>
#> 1 2017-03-14          0.00907
#> 2 2017-04-14          0.00069
#> 3 2017-05-14          0.01890
#> 4 2017-06-14          0.00803
#> 5 2017-07-14         -0.01998
#> 6 2017-08-14          0.00697
#> 
#> $sheet_two
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>         X__1 `Monthly return`
#>       <dttm>            <dbl>
#> 1 2017-03-14          0.00907
#> 2 2017-04-14          0.00069
#> 3 2017-05-14          0.01890
#> 4 2017-06-14          0.00803
#> 5 2017-07-14         -0.01998
#> 6 2017-08-14          0.00697
```

Comment: Thanks.  You're assuming "Monthly return" will appear in the second column, and I need something a bit more general.

Comment: @lebelinoz I assumed you actually meant this: "The exact location of the data varies from sheet to sheet: the only constant is that the first column is a date and the second column has "Monthly return" as the header. "

Answer (score 2):

In those cases it's important to know the possible conditions of your data. I'm gonna assume that you want only remove columns and rows that doesn't confrom your table.

I have this Excel book:
[image]

I added 3 blank columns at left becouse when I loaded in R with one column the program omits them. Thats for confirm that R omits empty cols at the left.

First: load data

```
library(xlsx)
dat <- read.xlsx('book.xlsx', sheetIndex = 1)
head(dat)

            MY.COMPANY.PTY.LTD            NA.
1             MC  Pension Fund           <NA>
2    GROSS PERFORMANCE DETAILS           <NA>
3 updated  by IG on 20/04/2017           <NA>
4                         <NA> Monthly return
5                       Mar-14         0.0097
6                       Apr-14          6e-04
```

Second: I added some cols with `NA` and `''` values in the case that your data contain some

```
dat$x2 <- NA
dat$x4 <- NA
head(dat)

            MY.COMPANY.PTY.LTD            NA. x2 x4
1             MC  Pension Fund           <NA> NA NA
2    GROSS PERFORMANCE DETAILS           <NA> NA NA
3 updated  by IG on 20/04/2017           <NA> NA NA
4                         <NA> Monthly return NA NA
5                       Mar-14         0.0097 NA NA
6                       Apr-14          6e-04 NA NA
```

Third: Remove columns when all values are `NA` and `''`. I have to deal with that kind of problems in past

```
colSelect <- apply(dat, 2, function(x) !(length(x) == length(which(x == '' | is.na(x)))))
dat2 <- dat[, colSelect]
head(dat2)

            MY.COMPANY.PTY.LTD            NA.
1             MC  Pension Fund           <NA>
2    GROSS PERFORMANCE DETAILS           <NA>
3 updated  by IG on 20/04/2017           <NA>
4                         <NA> Monthly return
5                       Mar-14         0.0097
6                       Apr-14          6e-04
```

Fourth: Keep only rows with complete observations (it's what I supose from your example)

```
rowSelect <- apply(dat2, 1, function(x) !any(is.na(x)))
dat3 <- dat2[rowSelect, ]
head(dat3)

   MY.COMPANY.PTY.LTD     NA.
5              Mar-14  0.0097
6              Apr-14   6e-04
7              May-14  0.0189
8              Jun-14   0.008
9              Jul-14 -0.0199
10             Ago-14 0.00697
```

Finally if you want to keep the header you can make something like this:

```
colnames(dat3) <- as.matrix(dat2[which(rowSelect)[1] - 1, ])
```

or

```
colnames(dat3) <- c('Month', as.character(dat2[which(rowSelect)[1] - 1, 2]))
dat3

    Month Monthly return
5  Mar-14         0.0097
6  Apr-14          6e-04
7  May-14         0.0189
8  Jun-14          0.008
9  Jul-14        -0.0199
10 Ago-14        0.00697
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would tackle it.

**STEP 1**
    Read the excel spreadsheet in `without` the headers.

**STEP 2**
     Find the row index for your string `Monthly return` in this case

**STEP 3**
    Filter from the identified row (or column or both), prettify a little and done.

Here is what a sample function looks like. It works for your example no matter where it is in the spreadsheet. You can play around with `regex` to make it more robust.

***Function Definition:***

```
library(xlsx)
extract_return <-  function(path = getwd(), filename = "Mysheet.xlsx", sheetnum = 1){
                       filepath = paste(path, "/", filename, sep = "")
                       input = read.xlsx(filepath, sheetnum, header = FALSE)
                       start_idx = which(input == "Monthly return", arr.ind = TRUE)[1]
                       output = input[start_idx:dim(input)[1],]
                       rownames(output) <- NULL
                       colnames(output) <- c("Date","Monthly Return")
                       output = output[-1, ]  
                       return(output)
                  }
```

***Example:***

```
final_df <- extract_return(
                path = "~/Desktop", 
                filename = "Apr2017.xlsx", 
                sheetnum = 2)
```

No matter ho many rows or columns you may have, the idea remains the same.. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you're assume Monthly Return is in the second column.

Comment: I have not made that assumption. You may feel it that way by the column names. If you drop the column names, or allow R to set default names, then Monthly return could be any column. My logic, finds the monthly return in the spreadsheet, treats it as the first row of the df and then extracts everything underneath it. Post extraction, it just deletes the first row. The logic does not look at the column position.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tidy alternative that avoids the multiple reads issue discussed above. However, when doing benchmarks, Rafael Zayas's answer still wins out.

```
library("tidyxl")
library("unpivotr")
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")

tidy_solution <- function() {
    raw <- xlsx_cells("messyExcel.xlsx")

    start <- raw %>%
        filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c("Monthly return"))) %>%
        select(row, col)

    month.col <- raw %>%
        filter(row >= start$row + 1, col == start$col - 1) %>%
        pivot_wider(date, col)

    return.col <- raw %>%
        filter(row >= start$row + 1, col == start$col) %>%
        pivot_wider(numeric, col)
 
    output <- cbind(month.col, return.col)
 }

# My Solution
            expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
tidy_solution() 29.0372 30.40305 32.13793 31.36925 32.9812 56.6455   100

# Rafael's
                expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
original_solution() 21.4405 23.8009 25.86874 25.10865 26.99945 59.4128   100
```

Answer (score -6):

```
grep("2014",dat)[1]
```

This gives you first column with year. Or use "-14" or whatever you have for years. 
Similar way grep("Monthly",dat)[1] gives you second column

Comment: That didn't really answer the question.

Comment: why not ? Explain in more details what you need.

Comment: You didn't even read the question.  I'm asking about how to automate tasks in Excel in R (specifically, how to look for the words "Monthly Return" in a cell), and you're telling me how to filter data based on strings, with no reference whatsoever to Excel.

Comment: If you need to import excel sheet into R, that is one, and if you need to parse this sheet, that is completely another. Learn to tell exactly what you need and don't blame others for your inability to explain your needs