# Extracting and importing untidy Excel tables into R to wrangle for Tableau export

Tags: r, excel, tableau-api

I want to read in to R an EXCEL tab that has the following content configuration into a more Tidy data format. The next picture shows how I want the content to look like once all of the code has run. The table below just represents file that will come in daily. Each day, the numbers and the date will change, but the format will be exactly the same. So I need to learn how to automate the extraction of the pieces of this format into R from EXCEL. The end goal is to stack the daily data into a format that can be exported to Tableau.

[image: Current EXCEL Tab Content]

[image: Final Tidy Format]

The image above (figure 2) represents the final format I want to arrive at. I know there are several packages to read in EXCEL data into R, however  I cannot figure out how I can possibly automate this tasks with readr or readxl etc... I am at least hoping some one has faced this type of problem before and can give me general directions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Excel in R: how to find the start cell in messy spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242467/reading-excel-in-r-how-to-find-the-start-cell-in-messy-spreadsheets)

Comment: Save it as a csv file and then read it with `read.csv("myfile.csv", skip = n)` to skip over the first n lines.  Use `readLines("myfile.csv", 1)` to get the MTD line.

Comment: thank you both. I think the Reading EXCEL in R responses will help me get started